# macro to delete all the rows containing specific values

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on a code to delete all the rows if there is a specific value in cells from column A. It works fine and delete all the rows I need, however the loop keeps going and it does not understand that should stop at cell "A400". Could you help me? Thank you!

```
Sub apaga1()
Dim PULO As String
Sheets("Sistema").Activate
Cells.Find("LF00").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
lastcell = Range("A400")
'APAGAR LFs
Do Until x = coelhoviado
    If Left(ActiveCell, 3) = "LF " Or Left(ActiveCell, 3) = "LFS" Or
    Left(ActiveCell, 4) = "LF00" Or Left(ActiveCell, 3) = "LFT" Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
        x = x + 1
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: `Do Until x = coelhoviado` What's `coelhoviado`?

Comment: sorry, its written lastcell as i defined previously instead of coelhoviado. But still not working

Comment: `lastcell = Range("A400")` `lastcell` is a range, not number. (Don't you need a `set`?)

Comment: Move your `x=x+1` after you `end if`.  it only increments on the deletes.  It needs to increment every loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub test()
 Dim lastcell As Long
 Dim i As Long
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim rng As Range

 Set ws = Sheets("Sistema")
 lastcell = 400

 For i = lastcell To 1 Step -1
  Set rng = ws.Range("A" & i)
  If Left(rng.Value, 3) = "LF " Or Left(rng.Value, 3) = "LFS" Or _
    Left(rng.Value, 4) = "LF00" Or Left(rng.Value, 3) = "LFT" Then
        rng.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
  End If
 Next

End Sub
```